# Adding multiple layers from file list or command line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, file-path

Is there a way to add multiple layers to QGIS at once from a list of paths?

I have about 150 rasters to investigate that intersect an area of interest. Their full path is collected in a text file, one image per line. I know I can open layers on the command line with `qgis path\to\imageone.tif path\for\imagetwo.tif` but there's too many to add that way.

I've tried redirecting `qgis < in-tiff-list.txt` but that doesn't work.

I can open each image in it's own session with something like `for /f %a in (in-tiff-list.txt) do qgis %a` but that's a lot of memory overhead and you can't compare layers to each other.

Perhaps there's a way to inject into a running instance of Qgis instead of starting a new session? e.g. `for {list of paths} do run "qgis --single-instance %file-path%"` (pseudo code).

I'm running QGIS 3.16 on Windows.

Comment: If the files are in the same folder, use `Data Source Manager` to select multiple files/the whole content of the folder at once.

Comment: Have you used the [Load Them All](https://github.com/gacarrillor/loadthemall) plugin before? Depending on the file-folder structure you could configure it to load all your rasters.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do afterwards, you could run an algorithm that expects raster layers as input: run it in batch mode, where you have sophisticated possibilities to load filenames, defining certain patterns for paths and/or using QGIS expressions to defained detailed instructions what files to use. Documentation does not mention it all, it is outdated: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/processing/batch_conversion.html

Comment: @Babel unfortunately the files are spread all over the place and not in one or even a handful of folders.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo oh that looks interesting! ...but not for this scenario as the filenames don't have common fragments to apply search patterns to. Bookmarked for later though, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The crude I solution I went with is:

- in a single folder build [vrt](/questions/tagged/vrt) for each raster in the list file
- drag and drop all the `.vrt` onto QGIS

I built the vrt files with (CMD Shell):

```
for /f %a in (in-tiff-list.txt) do ^
  (gdalbuildvrt staging-folder\%~na.vrt %a)
```

I'll have some more as yet unidentified legwork later to locate the home folder for each of the rasters but this solves the immediate visual need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Windows but with a POSIX subshell you could do

```sh
qgis (cat in-tiff-list.txt)
```

which is equivalent to `qgis path\to\imageone.tif path\for\imagetwo.tif`. maybe there is something similar in PowerShell